# How to write out an email with mutt, grep the file, then execute a command at new email

Tags: email, file, scripting, grep, mutt

I am trying to write a series of scripts that will execute other scripts on my server depending upon text from an email that was just received.  I am using mutt as a text based email client, but have no idea where to start for this.  I am hoping to understand how this works more than just solving the problem, because this project of mine is for fun. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Another option (which will possibly require more software and/or access, depending on your server setup) is to use [procmail](http://www.procmail.org/) (or one of the [similar](http://www.courier-mta.org/maildrop/) software packages) to process your email, and run the text of the email as input into your server-side scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Mailing list software does basically what you want. You can sign up or get removed to / from the mailing list by sending a special mails to the list manager. You can look at the open source [mailman](http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/index.html) software to see how they do it and base your solution on a similar approach.

Answer (score 0):

the previous answer is correct and most probably the easiest.

There is another possibility. 
I assume that this mail account corresponds to a linux/unix user and this user 
has a home directory. At the home directory you can add a file called .forward
and then you can forward all the incoming mail either to another address or pipe the incoming mail to a shell script. 
The .forward file -as far as I remember- should have execution permission as well as the
shell script you are forwarding your email.

It works. I have done this in the past.